# Using Switch Statement in R

Tags: r

I know the switch statement in R is not designed to work like it does in C++ for instance but I have read the documentation and can't seem to figure out why the following does not work

```
file.types <- c('bmp', 'jpeg', 'png', 'tiff', 'eps', 'pdf', 'ps')
  if(tolower(file.type) %in% file.types) {
    switch(file.type,
           bmp = bmp(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.',
                                    file.type, sep=''), 
                     width=res[2], height=res[1])
           jpeg = jpeg(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.',
                                      file.type, sep=''),
                     width=res[2], height=res[1])
           png = png(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.',
                                    file.type, sep=''),
                     width=res[2], height=res[1])
           tiff = tiff(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.',
                                      file.type, sep=''),
                       width=res[2], height=res[1])
           eps = postscript(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.',
                                           file.type, sep=''),
                            width=res[2], height=res[1])
           pdf = postscript(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.',
                                           file.type, sep=''),
                            width=res[2], height=res[1])
           ps = postscript(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.',
                                          file.type, sep=''),
                           width=res[2], height=res[1]))  
  } else {
      stop(paste(file.type,' is not supported', sep=''))
  }
```

I am getting the following error when file.type is 'jpeg'

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"           bmp = {bmp(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.', file.type, sep=''), width=res[2], height=res[1])}
       jpeg"
```

Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is syntax error. You are missing a `,` (comma) at the end of each option in the `switch`, e.g.

```
switch(file.type,
       bmp = bmp(filename=paste(file.location, file.name, '.', 
                                file.type, sep=''), 
                 width=res[2], height=res[1]),
                                             ^ here
```

The general form is

```
switch(foo,
       opt1 = statement1,
       opt2 = statement2,
       opt3 = ,
       opt4 = statement3)
```

Where both `opt3` and `opt4` return the value of `statement3`.

Comment: Right you are. Thanks!